# How to set the level of detail / smoothness / subdivision rate for SCNShape?

Tags: ios, objective-c, scenekit

I am currently trying to render a circle with SCNShapeNode in SceneKit. But unfortunately it does not render a perfect circle but an octagon.

Is there any way to set the render detail for SCNShape?

```
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter: CGPointMake(0, 0) radius: 2 startAngle: 0.0 endAngle: M_PI * 2.0f clockwise: NO];

SCNShape *shape = [SCNShape shapeWithPath:path extrusionDepth: 1.0];
shape.firstMaterial.diffuse.contents = [UIColor colorWithRed: 1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];    

SCNNode *shapeNode = [SCNNode nodeWithGeometry: shape];
[scene.rootNode addChildNode: shapeNode];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the docs:

> The path’s flatness (see setFlatness: in NSBezierPath Class Reference) determines the level of detail SceneKit uses in building a three-dimensional shape from the path—a larger flatness value results in fewer polygons to render, increasing performance.

Conversely, a lower flatness value results in a smoother shape.

Bezier path flatness is an odd fit for this API because it measures in terms of pixels/points, and by default a "point" for an `SCNShape` is one unit of scene (or local node) space. So if your shape is 10 scene units wide, it's like trying to render a path in 10 pixels in 2D... You need a *really* low flatness value for it to be smooth.

To answer the question in your non-answer: the `subdivisionLevel` stuff and edge creases business aren't really for use with `SCNShape` — they're for custom geometry that's designed for use with [subdivision surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdivision_surface) rendering.

Comment: Thank you (adding useless characters as SOF does not allow me to thank you without this comment having 15 characters.)

Comment: @Max [Don't leave "thank you" comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126180/258777).  Use an upvote/accept instead.

Comment: This is an important note from @rickster: UIBezierPath is working in Pixel units which is way off for most SceneKit stuff (think ARKit 1 unit = 1 m). Rather than trying to fit `UIBezierPath.flatness` use `SCNNode.scale`. I found that UIBezierPath is not working right when going < `0.01`.